# DataGrid error when selecting a row

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, itemssource

The following problem is not simple to explain.
I have a Window which contains a DataGrid, and a ViewModel for the window.
The window.DataContext holds the ViewModel.
the DataGrid.ItemSource holds an ObservableCollection.
DataGrid's RowStyle's IsSelected Property is Binded to an IsSelected property in the PointData.

When I close the window and open a new one... and populate it with the old ViewModel data.
Selecting an "old" row throws an annoying Exception which says:
"Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute"

If anyone has an idea of solving this situation I would truely appreaciate the help. 
Thanks

Comment: Would help if you would post your xaml with the datagrid and at least the part of the viewmodel which you are binding to.

Answer (score 1):

Normally this exception occurs when you modify a collection while using IEnumerable (an Enumerator) to loop through the collection. The keyword `foreach` uses this interface.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I cant find the place where it is being modified.

Comment: It happens in the (IsSelected) binding somewhere

Comment: Or in the construction/opening of the form. Really, without code we can't help.